# Rsyslog running on RHEL unable to forward messages - rsyslogd: action 'action 8' suspended

Tags: rhel, rsyslog

I'm trying to configure an rsyslog agent which will forward the log messages to a centralized server. However, I get the following error. The link provided in the error message does not specify the root cause of the error.

```
rsyslogd: action 'action 8' suspended, next retry is Wed Jan 16 2:52:17 2019 [v8.24.0-34.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
```

Comment: Also asked on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/975519/294707), where there is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further troubleshooting, I found that selinux was enabled in **enforcing mode** which led to block rsyslog to send logs. 
Changed selinux mode to permissive, reboot the server and it started working.